# Accessing all the keys under classesroot from registry with c#

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I have a program which i try is to read all the keys under classesroot but when i do it with `GetSubKeyNames()` many keys are skipped i only get the key which contains another sub key on it.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot;
foreach (string tempKeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
{
     MessageBox.Show(tempKeyName);
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um6mZ.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce the misbehavior: `MyTextBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, key.GetSubKeyNames());` *shows* `._sln70` among the other keys

Comment: I am just a beginner in c# so can i have the code??? That's will be a great concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code shows all the registry keys under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. If it doesn't work for you, edit your question telling us Windows version and maybe if you are under a corporate network.

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.ClassesRoot;
// Print out the keys.
PrintKeys(rk);
```

PrintKeys:

```
static void PrintKeys(RegistryKey rkey)
{

    // Retrieve all the subkeys for the specified key.
    String[] names = rkey.GetSubKeyNames();

    Console.WriteLine("Subkeys of " + rkey.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");

    // Print the contents of the array to the console.
    foreach (String s in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Source:[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.classesroot(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Same problem arises i am using windows 7 32 bit

Comment: Well, then i can't only think of a permissions issue or maybe a corrupted registry

Comment: may be you are right but how can i know its a corrupted registry entry cause no error is throwing

Answer (score 0):

**JANUARY 2022 - This issue is due to breaking changes introduced in the framework's registry searching library that apparently are not well known**

For those searching and still coming up with incorrect registry key results this is due to the 32/64 redirecting in place by Microsoft.  This means the old route of iterating for a key in the `ClassesRoot` hive using `Registry.ClassesRoot` could unknowingly search the `Wow6432` key instead.

The new route is to look it up using the base key while explicitly defining where it should search.  Here's the current way to correctly search for a key if you are having this trouble:

```
RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Registry64)
```

*Note the use of the `RegistryKey` static member instead of `Registry`*

You can explicitly tell it to look in `Registry32`, `Registry64`, or `Default` - the later of which is what the old process of `Registry.ClassesRoot` appears to follow.